# Android Card view random text comes in the view from other card values

Tags: android, cardview

In Android card view when I open the category page first, it is all good, but when I scroll to bottom and again scroll to top the values from other cards come to the hidden values of some above cards. Need Help..

Folowing is the fragment file of the product list

Fragment File:

public class ProductsList extends Fragment {

```
View view;

@BindView(R.id.categoryRecyclerView)
RecyclerView productsRecyclerView;
public static int categoryPosition;
@BindView(R.id.noProductAddedLayout)
LinearLayout noProductAddedLayout;
@BindView(R.id.contShopping)
Button contShopping;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category_list, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    MainActivity.title.setText(SplashScreen.categoryListResponseData.get(categoryPosition).getCategory_name());
    setProductsData();
    contShopping.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).removeCurrentFragmentAndMoveBack();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).lockUnlockDrawer(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    MainActivity.search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Config.getCartList(getActivity(), true);

}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    MainActivity.search.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void setProductsData() {
    if (SplashScreen.categoryListResponseData.get(categoryPosition).getProducts().size() > 0) {
        ProductListAdapter productListAdapter;
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        productsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        productListAdapter = new ProductListAdapter(getActivity(), SplashScreen.categoryListResponseData.get(categoryPosition).getProducts(), categoryPosition);
        productsRecyclerView.setAdapter(productListAdapter);
    } else {
        noProductAddedLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

}

Adapter file:

```
 public class ProductListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeProductsViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<Product> productList;
    int categoryPosition;
    String mrp;
    String sellPrice;
    public ProductListAdapter(Context context, List<Product> productList, int categoryPosition) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productList = productList;
        this.categoryPosition = categoryPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public HomeProductsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.home_products_list_items, null);
        HomeProductsViewHolder homeProductsViewHolder = new HomeProductsViewHolder(context, view, productList);
        return homeProductsViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final HomeProductsViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        holder.cardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.cardView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.productName.setText(productList.get(position).getProductName());
        holder.price.setText(MainActivity.currency + " " + productList.get(position).getSellprice());
        try {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(productList.get(position).getImages().get(0))
                    .resize(Integer.parseInt(context.getResources().getString(R.string.targetProductImageWidth)), Integer.parseInt(context.getResources().getString(R.string.targetProductImageHeight)))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.defaultimage)
                    .into(holder.image);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            double discountPercentage = Integer.parseInt(productList.get(position).getMrpprice()) - Integer.parseInt(productList.get(position).getSellprice());
            Log.d("percentage", discountPercentage + "");
            discountPercentage = (discountPercentage / Integer.parseInt(productList.get(position).getMrpprice())) * 100;
            if ((int) Math.round(discountPercentage) > 0) {
                holder.discountPercentage.setText(((int) Math.round(discountPercentage) + "% Off"));
            } else {
                holder.discountPercentage.setText("");
            }
            mrp = productList.get(position).getMrpprice();
            sellPrice = productList.get(position).getSellprice();
            Log.i("MRP PRICE------>>>>", mrp +" a");
            Log.i("Sell Price PRICE->>", sellPrice +" b");
            holder.actualPrice.setText(MainActivity.currency + " " + productList.get(position).getMrpprice());
            holder.actualPrice.setPaintFlags(holder.actualPrice.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ProductDetail.productList.clear();
                ProductDetail.productList.addAll(productList);
                ProductDetail productDetail = new ProductDetail();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("position", position);
                productDetail.setArguments(bundle);
                ((MainActivity) context).loadFragment(productDetail, true);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RecyclerView` is called like that because its `View`s are reused when you scroll. Because of that, you always have to set all attributes to all the `View`s in each grid cell. For example you have to assign an empty `String` ("") as text to `holder.discountPercentage` if the percentage value is <= 0.

Another thing: you need the try-catch block because you want to calculate the value for the `double discountPercentage`. After this value is known, you can proceed outside of the try-catch block.

```
double discountPercentage = 0;
try {
    double discountPercentage = Integer.parseInt(productList.get(position).getMrpprice()) - Integer.parseInt(productList.get(position).getSellprice());
    Log.d("percentage", discountPercentage + "");
    discountPercentage = (discountPercentage / Integer.parseInt(productList.get(position).getMrpprice())) * 100;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // Log exception here 
}
finally{
    // either you managed to calculate a value for discountPercentage
    // or it is still zero
    // Anyway, you can set the text for the TextView now:
    if ((int) Math.round(discountPercentage) > 0) {
        holder.discountPercentage.setText(((int) Math.round(discountPercentage) + "% Off"));
    }
    // Note: there always has to be an "else" block, 
    // or the recycled View will keep the content from 
    // the previous call to onBindViewHolder()
    else {
         holder.discountPercentage.setText("");
    }
}
// as far as I can see, the TextView for the actual price
// does not depend on the discountPercentage
// so it can stay outside of the try-catch block
holder.actualPrice.setText(MainActivity.currency + " " + productList.get(position).getMrpprice());
holder.actualPrice.setPaintFlags(holder.actualPrice.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```